# Unusual GET Request

Tags: malware, botnet

I am getting unusual get requests to my server: `/op69okl?name=http://www.ntdtv.com/` or `/op69okl?name=http://www.epochtimes.com/` or something similar with other sites in the param. Doing some searching for `op69okl` seems like a username of a porn account.

To clarify my interest in this question: I am software developer, but I started doing reverse engineering and learning more about malware recently. So I am still too noob to approach this systematically.

Requests comes from IP addresses in China, almost all IPs are different and rarely repeat. Since IP are so different it leads me to believe they are bots. I suppose they could be probing for a vulnerability and expecting a certain response. In my case my server (which is not running any common framework) is not returning 404 to this request, but rather reroutes to a default page. I wonder if that's why the bot keeps trying my IP?

I am curios how to investigate this further. I am currently learning how to catch malware, I am thinking as a first step to map out IP addresses of the incoming requests and get more insight where they come from and how often (it started 3 days ago; not very frequent). Then I want to setup a new server and see if I can "catch" the same request again. WordPress or another common framework would work OK for this, I think.

What else can I do to investigate this? I am taking this as a real life learning opportunity.

P.S. I am very curious why the bot is passing the `?name=` like this. Would love to find out.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/is-there-404-spam/

Comment: There is not much to investigate on your end if there isn't a vulnerability. The attacker is testing for something. What that is is not obvious.

Comment: At first glance it seems that someone is testing for RFI, but I can't tell why he is trying with this particular path and param (*"/op69okl?name="*) since it doesn't exist on your side? Are all the requests in this form?

Comment: @game0ver Yeah, all requests I've seen so far are in this form. At schroeder: I saw this page and the answer, but it's nothing substantial I think.

Comment: @game0ver Would it mean that those sites like `http://www.ntdtv.com` are potentially in control of the botnet owner?

Comment: No, that's not obligatory. Also If all the "weird" requests in your logs are grouped per certain hours then it's possible that some automated tool is fuzzing to find potential vulnerabilities...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48512927/apache-random-ips-in-access-log-trying-to-execute-scripts

suggests it's a probe from the great firewall of china, looking for gateways that allow folks to get out to blocked sites. I can't verify empirically but it seems plausible for those domains to fit that category.

It could be interesting to try to return the contents of those domains and see what the robot does in response.